# Apache won't start after changing virtualhost

Tags: apache

So I tried forcing https site-wide by putting a redirect in virtualhost and now apache won't start. Here's the virtualhost file:

```
Listen 80 443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect permanent / https://www.tedspikes.com/ 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName tedspikes.com
    ServerAlias www.tedspikes.com
    SSLEngine On
    <Directory />
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I start apache, it throws this:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

Which I took as "someone is listening my port 80". Here's the kicker:

```
ted@Home:~$ sudo netstat -nlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      889/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      903/pptpd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      987/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      889/sshd
udp        0      0 188.166.36.165:123      0.0.0.0:*                           1367/ntpd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           1367/ntpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           1367/ntpd
udp6       0      0 fe80::601:37ff:fefd:123 :::*                                1367/ntpd
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                1367/ntpd
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                1367/ntpd
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9254     895/acpid           /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9515     987/mysqld          /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7004     1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8919     691/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     7651     324/systemd-udevd   /run/udev/control
```

So, apache won't start because someone is hogging port 80, but there's no one on that port! What's going on? Did I break something in virtualhost?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in `Listen` Directive. You cannot mention more than one interface/port with a single `Listen` directive and so you have to use multiple ones like,

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
```

Other than that other rules look fine. Regarding the https redirection you can use below rule which is more generic and will save you from unexpected issues.

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Other than that not sure why you are getting `Address already in use` error.

Comment: Fixed the listen directive, now it throws two errors, both for 80 and 443 ports.

Regarding modrewrite, apache documentation says it's a bad way to do ssl redirects and recommends redirecting via virtualhost.